# Is it possible to access a ListView item from BackgroundWorker ProgressChanged?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a UI being updated by BackgroundWorker ProgressChanged. It has a progress bar, and a listview which displays the filename of each item being worked on by the backgroundworker.

I only want to add an item to the listview if it is a new file, so I tried to use a comparison between the last item in the listview and the current filename.

This throws a TargetInvocation error, however.

```
void m_oWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        var r = Enumerable.Empty<ListViewItem>();
        if (this.listView1.Items.Count > 0)
            r = this.listView1.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>();

        var last = r.LastOrDefault();

        if (last.Text != CurrentTrack.Name)
        {
            ListViewItem LVI = new ListViewItem(currentTrack.Name);
            LVI.SubItems.Add(keywords);
            LVI.SubItems.Add("Updated");
            listView1.Items.Add(LVI);
            listView1.TopItem = LVI;
            listView1.EnsureVisible(listView1.Items.Count - 1);
        }


        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        lblStatus.Text = "Processing......" + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
    }
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Which line number you got exception raise?

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform UI changes on the UI thread.  This can be achieved using the following code:

```
frmMain()
{
    Worker_ProgressChanged = new Worker_ProgressChanged_Delegate(m_oWorker_ProgressChanged);
}

delegate void Worker_ProgressChanged_Delegate(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e);
Worker_ProgressChanged_Delegate Worker_ProcessChanged;
void m_oWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(Worker_ProgressChanged, sender, e);
    }
    else
    {
        ... Add list items etc.
    }
```

If the worker thread calls this method, InvokeRequired will be true.  The form will then invoke the same method using its thread (the UI thread). This time InvokeRequired is false and the function executes on the correct thread.

**Edit:** Move add list items to else block based upon comment

Comment: Make sure you put the `add list items etc.` in the else clause of the if statement

Answer (score 0):

Does this throw the same error?

```
    void m_oWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem last = null;
        if (this.listView1.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            last = this.listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1];
        }
        if (last == null || last.Text != CurrentTrack.Name)
        {
            ListViewItem LVI = new ListViewItem(currentTrack.Name);
            LVI.SubItems.Add(keywords);
            LVI.SubItems.Add("Updated");
            listView1.Items.Add(LVI);
            listView1.TopItem = LVI;
            listView1.EnsureVisible(listView1.Items.Count - 1);
        }

        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        lblStatus.Text = "Processing......" + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
    }
```